# find the domain and range and sketch the graph of $g(x) = \sqrt{9 - x^2}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've found the domain but how do we find the range and sketch graph. is there a way to find the range. Also the graph of square root is like $e^x$ but facing downwards towards $x$ axis while $x^2$ is a parabola and $9$ units upwards. I just don't get the graph.

Comment: Hints: $g(x) \ge 0$ and $g(x)^2+x^2=3^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a function $g(x) = \sqrt{9 - x^2},$ we can square it to find $g^2(x) = 9 - x^2.$

Adding $x^2$ to both sides, we now have $g^2(x) + x^2 = 9.$ Replace $g(x) = y$ to get $x^2 + y^2 = 9$.

We know that $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ is the equation for a circle of radius $r,$ so we'll sketch a circle of radius $3$ (because $3^2 = 9$) centered around the origin.

However, since in our original problem it was a square root, we'll assume the positive root and sketch only the top half of a circle.

The domain and range can be found, respectively, as $\left[-3, 3\right]$ and $\left[0, 3\right],$ which can be determined from the sketch.

Ask as many questions as you can, as my problem solving isn't necessarily spot-on. ;-)

Comment: okay if it's like that how will i solve this one then. f(x) = 1 - square root 1 - x^2.

Comment: For the function `f(x) = 1 - \sqrt(1 - x^2)`, we'll first figure out the `\sqrt(1 - x^2)` part. Squaring both sides and adding `x^2`, we have `x^2 + h^2(x) = 1`, where `h(x) = \sqrt(1 - x^2)`. This is the top half of a circle of radius `1` centered around the origin. Now subtract it from `1`, leaving the bottom half of a circle centered around the point `(0, 1)`.